# How to run Web Worker on Micro-frontend?

Tags: reactjs, web-worker, micro-frontend

I'm using React, Webpack and adopting the Micro-frontend model.
I have two simple apps as follows:

1. App A (Shell app)
2. App B (Remote app).

`App B` uses a simple Web Worker as follows:
`new Worker(new URL("./myworker.ts", import.meta.url))`

`App B` runs normally, but when running on `App A`, it crashes:
`Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to construct 'Worker': Script at 'appB.com/worker.js' cannot be accessed from origin 'appA.com'`

I know there is a method that is to use `Blob`, but in this case, I don't know how to do that because Worker is on `App B` itself.
One more thing, I want `App B` to be able to run both standalone and to be able to run well on shell app (`App A`).
Is there any solution? Thank

Comment: Have you tried using `importScripts` from a worker defined in app A to pull in the script underlying the worker from app B?

Comment: @morganney `app A` is not creating a worker. The worker is from B. But it cannot run. So, the function of app B can't run correctly

Comment: I know. Read my first comment more carefully.

Comment: @morganney Thank you. I've tried, but no luck :(

Comment: sorry i don't understand where `app b` is running and why is it running in `app a`

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Use Blob Which  creates a file-like object in memory.  Blob object can create a Web Worker.

Blob object is not subject to the same security restrictions as a regular file aka you can create a Web Worker from a Blob even if the two origins are different.

```
const workerBlob = new Blob([workerSource],               {type: "application/javascript"});
  const worker = new Worker(workerBlob);
```

Solution 2: Use Service Workers as  ways to create background workers that can run even when the user is not actively using the application. Use Service Workers to create a Web Worker that is accessible from both App A and App B.

```
const sw = new ServiceWorker();
  sw.register("./serviceworker.js");

  const worker = new Worker("/serviceworker.js/worker.js");
```

same advantage above as Blob

Solution 3: Use Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) to allow the worker script to be loaded from a different origin. This can be done by adding the  headers to the worker script:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
```

references :

- [Service worker documentation:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API)
- [CORS documentation:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)